# How can I create a copy of mysql database for offline use on PhoneGap?

Tags: cordova, web-sql

We are creating an app that will be used offline the majority of the time. What we are looking to do is create a copy of a few tables from our live database and periodically copy that database down to the PhoneGap application (never pushing from PhoneGap to live).

I could do an insert in PhoneGap for every record the first time the app runs (user would be in the office with access to their WiFi) and then systematically determine which records on the Live DB have been updated since the last 'sync' and update those records in the PhoneGap app, but it would be GREAT if I could do a more brute-force dump of the live DB to a file and replace the local PhoneGap copy?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know how much data you need to store locally but if you can limit it to 5mb you can use `json` and `localStorage` instead of a local db.

When your app make a request for data, return it all at once with a timestamp in the end and use that to smartly return only updated data. A call like `yourhost.com/retrieveData` would return all the data and `yourhost.com/retrieveData/timestampParam` returns only the data updated after the timestamp.

Returning something like:

```
{ "table1" : [{"col1":"data1","col2":"data2"},{"col1":"data3","col2":"data4"}],
  "table2" : [{"col3":"data5","col4":"data6"},{"col3":"data5","col4":"data6"}], 
  "timestamp" : 1234567 } //this should be optimized for your needs, it's just a generic example.
```

When the app starts, before anything else do something along these lines and you'll be sure your app is always up to date:

```
Check if the data is stored
    If there isn't, or if the user is online or if the timestamp is too old, or you can perform any check you might need here
       Retrieve the data again using the stored timestamp
       Update the local data
       Store the timestamp returned
    If none of the above applies, the app is good to run
```

I used that approach in several apps. I've chosen it over a database because it's simpler to implement and to maintain.

Comment: All of the data is definitely going to be larger than 5MB in json. Is the limit 5MB total or 5MB per file/object?

Comment: 5MB is the maximum size of the data you can save on local storage. But AFAIK you are also limited on web sql, 5mb for iOS (can be extended to 10 if the user authorizes) and 12mb for android if I remember right. Need to search to be sure though. I'll try to find something when I get home. But if you need much more than that I'm pretty sure you'll have to go native.

Comment: Thanks caiocpricci2, I'm actually looking to use the PG-SQLite Plugin https://github.com/pgsqlite/PG-SQLitePlugin-iOS though I'm having trouble getting the plugin working with my project :s

Comment: Plugins can be tough on the beginning but after the first it gets easier, believe me, been there before. Don't give up! I can't find any reliable source with actual numbers for the limits but I just have to keep looking, I'm sure I've read it somewhere